# Bluetooth doesn't work on Linux Mint 18.2

Tags: linux-mint, bluetooth

I did not use bluetooth on a `Linux` system before, but I would like to use it right now. I tried to use it and it didn't work at all. Here are some information:

`dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`

```
[   21.787508] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   21.787528] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   21.787530] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   21.787532] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   21.787535] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   21.961854] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   21.962852] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[   21.978852] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[   21.978855] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[   24.604038] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0a0a tx timeout
[   26.844010] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch command 0a0a failed (-19)
[   28.956044] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   37.084103] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)
[   39.420553] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   47.583855] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)
[   47.998349] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   47.998351] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   47.998355] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

In addition:

`hciconfig -a`

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:318 acl:0 sco:0 events:8 errors:0
    TX bytes:43 acl:0 sco:0 commands:11 errors:0
    Features: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
    Packet type: DM1 DH1 HV1 
    Link policy: 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
```

`uname -a`

```
Linux xena-HP-Notebook 4.15.0-34-generic #37~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 28 10:44:06 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have tried editing the .config file as suggested by user Goro below. I have also uninstalled Blueberry and installed Blueman in hopes that it might work. I have googled extensively and found that a lot of users face similar issues that correct themselves after a reboot. This hasn't happened in my case. My kernel is updated to the latest one offered under Software Manager.

EDIT: I think bluetooth has been discontinued for kernel 4.15 and newer. I read it someplace. Anyway, it still doesn't work and I'm giving up now.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in [Linux Mint forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=249914), you can try the following:

```
-Change #AutoEnable=false to AutoEnable=true in the /etc/bluetooth/main.conf (notice new line is un-commented)
-Unpair the headset
-Restart the bluetooth service sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
-Pair your headset again and connect it
-Go to sound settings. From the output device tab you should now see the headset listed along with other output device like internal speakers
-Choose it as the sound output device.
```

Comment: This doesn't help. Bluetooth is still down and bluetooth manager shows absolutely nothing on screen.